# Button location in listview android

Tags: android, android-layout, popup

I have a button on the listview when click on that will show popup. I have implemented that successfully. But the issue is that i want to display popup on the clicked button position.

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout,null);             
    pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 250, true);
    pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY,  30, 40);
    pwindo.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    pwindo.setTouchable(true); 
    pwindo.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {



            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                pwindo.dismiss();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Button code

```
 vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
vi.findViewById(R.id.statusImage).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showPopup();//to display popup thats given above
        }
    });
```

Comment: where is your buttons ?

Comment: no answer for this ??

Comment: button will be in right of listviw.but there can be multiple button with same id@Hardik

Comment: can you show a screen shots, so it will be easier to understand.

Comment: post your button code also.

Comment: @user2291423 did you checked answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set buttons tag as its position, and onClick you need to get it:

```
button.setTag(position);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
        // Do whatever you like with position
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

when the button is clicked you can get the position of the item in the list. Use

```
list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

to get the buttin postion. substract the FirstVisiblePosition from the position. you will get the click postion. and you can show the pop up in that postion.

Answer (score 0):

You can get position for button click in listview by following code.

```
 (vi.findViewById(R.id.statusImage)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
       Toast.makeText(Classname.this, "POSITION"+ position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       showPopup();
    }
 });
```

Comment: ok but can u tell me how to show the popup on that position ?

Comment: On that position means ?? You only need to show popup or more ?

Comment: continuing Hardik's answer, you can position the toast by using the following method toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, x, y) where x and y are the offset. you can calculate x and y by using the list.getFirstVisiblePosition() method as 'bill gates' suggested in his answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use QuickAction. Examples :

- http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/
- http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-apps/quick-action-demo/
- https://github.com/alhneiti/Android-QuickAction